# Android studio kotlin function throw exeption

Tags: android, kotlin, exception

Im developing an app using kotlin and MVVM architecture.I have the three layers activity,viewModel and repository, in repository i have renameDirectory() function it does some network calling to rename a directory, the function can throw an exception if the network response returns an error the problem is that the catch block in the activity layer does not catch the exception.

renameDirectory in repository

```
suspend fun renameDirectory(token : String,directory: Directory) {
    val resp = maApi.renameDirectory("jwt $token",directory)
    if(resp.isSuccessful)
        return

    val gson = Gson()
    val type = object : TypeToken<ErrorResponse>() {}.type
    val errorResponse =
        gson.fromJson<ErrorResponse>(resp.errorBody()!!.charStream(), type)

    throw Exception(errorResponse.error)
}
```

code in viewModel that calls the function

```
suspend fun renameDirectory(directory: Directory){
    viewModelScope.launch (Dispatchers.IO){
        directoriesRepository.renameDirectory(userResp!!.token!!,directory)
    }
}
```

code in activity to calls the function and handle exceptions

```
try {
                viewModel.renameDirectory(directory)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    horizontalProgress.toggle()
                    activityView.snackBar("Directory has been renamed successfully")
                    currentFragment.clearSelection()
                }

            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                Log.d("IO Exception=>", ex.toString())                
            } catch (ex: HttpException) {
                Log.d("Http Exception=>", ex.message())     
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                this.cancel()
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    horizontalProgress.toggle()
                    activityView.snackBar(ex.message!!)
                }
            }
```

when renameDirectory in repository calls throw Exception() the app stops,why the code in activity does not handle the exception?

Comment: By using `viewModelScope.launch()` you run inner `renameDirectory()` asynchronously. Code in the activity does not really wait for `renameDirectory()` to complete, it does not care about its errors.

Comment: Also, you need to be careful when adding `withContext()` or doing other coroutine stuff in exception handlers or finally block. Note that if the exception would be related to the fact that the coroutine failed or was cancelled, you would get an exception when trying to run `withContext()`. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#run-non-cancellable-block

Comment: Thanks @broot you're right i found a solution.